# MongoDB Pojo get anonimos class

Tags: java, mongodb

I've have a java project where i use MongoDB,
I use pojoCodeRegistery

i have created a small helper class for my project and my question is :

this works fine :

```
   
   public MongoCollection<Client> getClientsCollection() {
        MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase(dbNAme);
        return db.getCollection("clients", Client.class);
   } 

   
``
but i want to achieve this :
```

```
  public MongoCollection<SomeClass> getSomeClassCollection(String collectionName,Class someClass) {
               
       MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase(dbNAme);
       return db.getCollection("clients", SomeClass.class);
  }
```

```
Any advise ?
```

Comment: if you want to create generic method for all collections then you need to method signature MongoCollection<SomeClass> to MongoCollection<Object> and can cast at the time of use. But this will create a more bugs  in code in future. Instead of this you can create an interface with generics and extend it for specific implmenation.